# Nestjs how to change socket.io message data

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nestjs

If the message data is not null, I can edit value like this:

```
context.switchToWs().getData().custom = true
```

But, how to change it, if the message data is null?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you solve it? I guess the solution has something to do with the interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Try please this way:

```js
const data = context.switchToWs().getData();

data = {
  ...data,
  custom: true
}
```

Comment: You just create a new object, `context.switchToWs().getData()` still the old value

Comment: if you want to change the only `custom` property of data even if data is null, before setting it you need to replace null to object and add `custom` property to it. If I'm wrong please clarify your question and I will try to edit my answer

Comment: Yes, I need to replace the `null` to object. But how to do this ? I need something like `context.switchToWs().setData()`, so I can use the new value in the flowed interceptors

Comment: Oh, I got the question. Maybe it is not a good solution for using the approach that you mentioned. Did you try reflection and meta data? Seems that it is what you need https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context#reflection-and-metadata

Comment: The custom value is based on incoming socket message data, so metadata can't resolve my problem.